# Excel download not happening from server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to download an Excel file from the server on a button click, but it is not happening. It simply executes the code but the download is not happening.

```
Protected Sub btn_dwnldexcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_dwnldexcel.Click
        Dim fileToDownload = Server.MapPath("./Data/nd_format.xls")
        ''Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Dim cd = New ContentDisposition()
        cd.Inline = False
        cd.FileName = Path.GetFileName(fileToDownload)
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString())
        Dim fileData As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToDownload)
        Response.OutputStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)
End Sub
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this in Visual Studio? Did you try stepping through in debug mode to see where the issue is? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask; the purpose of this site is not to debug your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to send the data from the same page, it is better to use a generic handler which does not have the overheads of processing an aspx page.

So, if you add a new item to the project and find "Generic handler (.ashx)" (or similar), and use code like this:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.IO

Public Class DownloadExcelFile
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Dim actualFile = Server.MapPath("~/Data/nd_format.xls")

        If File.Exists(actualFile) Then
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & Path.GetFileName(actualFile) & """")
            context.Response.TransmitFile(actualFile)

        Else
            context.Response.Clear()
            context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404
            context.Response.Write("<html><head><title>File not found</title><style>body {font-family: Arial,sans-serif;}</style></head><body><h1>File not found</h1><p>Error.</p></body></html>")
            context.Response.End()

         End If

    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Then you can use a hyperlink instead of a Button:

```html
<a href="DownloadExcelFile.ashx">Download Excel File</a>
```

(You can style the hyperlink as a button with CSS if required.)